# hide collapsible fieldsets on node edit

Tags: 6

I understand how to edit a specific content type with form_alter

```
my_module_form_node_form_alter(&$form, $form_state) {

  $type = $form['#node']->type;

  if ($type == 'my_content_type') {

  } 
}
```

I would like to hide all collapsible fieldsets EXCEPT scheduling. How do I only target these other fieldsets to hide?

http://screencast.com/t/ozHu5esPGc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dull ax approach would be to cycle through your `$form` looking for fieldsets and unsetting (now setting `#access` to `FALSE`) all but the one you want to keep, eg, something along the lines of...

```
// drupal_set_message('<pre>' . print_r($form, TRUE) . '</pre>');
foreach($form as $key => $field) {
  if ($key != 'field_FIELDNAME' && is_array($field)  && $field['#type']=='fieldset' && $field['#collapsible']) {
    // unset($form[$key]);          // ADDITION/EDIT: '#access' below is a better/working approach
    $form[$key]['#access'] = FALSE; // than unset if required fields are in the fieldset :)
  }
}
```

...with the `drupal_set_message()` helping to get the `field_FIELDNAME` for your scheduling fieldset.

Just realize that without further logic, you would never be able to edit any fields inside these fieldsets again.

Another option might be to check out the [nodeformcols](https://drupal.org/project/nodeformcols) module that makes lengthy node forms a bit nicer and does contain this functionality out of the box for both fields as well as fieldsets.

Comment: What do you mean "you would never be able to edit any fields inside these fieldsets again." I don't want the user to edit the fields inside these ever again, on this particular node type. That is the point of hiding them.

Comment: well, just pointing out what might not be obvious.  perhaps you would want an admin to be able to change them in the future.  if so, you might want to put in logic for that (based on $user->uid or role).  you also might want to make sure that logic is in there so that this only happens on the edit page, not the initial node add, etc.

Comment: see also change to use '#access' instead of unset()ing.  I just tried it the first way and it screws up if you have required fields in the fieldset :(

Comment: I this is not the solution but had to pick something. Just wanted to hide certain fields on one content type. I used CSS advanced selectors. There should be a module for this to make a simple node edit for users

Answer (score 0):

by using #attached property you can add js to this form in this form alter only.
And using jQuery .hide() function you can hide the divs of those fieldsets that you don't require. This way entire fieldset will get hidden

Comment: But how do you rarfe specific fields

Comment: As Drupal generates lot of markup, find the CSS class of the div tag encloses the fieldset you want to hide. Please note that this will hide the fieldset just aesthetically, in actual form the fields will be present.